# create table from javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html

I've never been good with coding and what I did was mainly PHP not javascript. This is running on a Windows server that I have no ability to install anything new on.

I have a web page that someone else built that I am trying to reformat. The current one is an OpenLayers map.

I want to take the information on the map and put it on a table.

A PowerShell script outputs data to a txt file.

The web page imports that data does a few different things to it.

I end up with three columns of stuff I want to put on the table and there just shy of 20 rows.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Office</td>
    <td>Server Ping</td>
    <td>Circuit Ping</td>
</table>


function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = fullname;
    cell2.innerHTML = pingResultHTML;
    cell3.innerHTML = circuitPrimaryResultHTML; 
    };
```

If needed I can post more or all of the page's code.

I'm operating under the assumption that if the variables can be used to populate info for popups on the map I should be able to just redirect them into a table.

Edit:
Here is additional info.
This is what calls the data from the txt file.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
};

xmlhttp.open("GET","latest_results_list.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;

var mySplitResult;
mySplitResult = xmlDoc.split("\r\n");
for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++)
  {
    var locationStringCleaned = mySplitResult[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");


    officeParameters = locationStringCleaned.split(",");
    officelocation = officeParameters[0];
    pingStatus = officeParameters[1];
    pingTime = officeParameters[2];
    primaryCircuit = officeParameters[3];
    primaryCircuitTime = officeParameters[4];


    addNewLocation(officelocation, pingStatus, pingTime, primaryCircuit, primaryCircuitTime);
```

This adds the site name.

```
        if (officename == "SHO"){
fullname = "Stevens Point, WI";
    } else if (officename == "RIC"){
fullname = "Richmond, VA";
    } else if (officename == "DAV"){
fullname = "Davenport, IA";
    } else if (officename == "GOL"){
fullname = "Goldsboro, NC";
    } else if (officename == "IRV"){
fullname = "Irvine, CA";
    } else if (officename == "MON"){
fullname = "Montgomery, AL";
    } else if (officename == "MAD"){
fullname = "Madison, WI";
    } else if (officename == "SAL"){
fullname = "Salem, OR";
    } else if (officename == "SCO"){
fullname = "Scottsdale, AZ";
    } else if (officename == "WES"){
fullname = "Westford, MA";
    } else if (officename == "FRE"){
fullname = "Freeport, IL";
    } else if (officename == "MIL"){
fullname = "Milwaukee, WI";
    } else if (officename == "AVI"){
fullname = "Stevens Point, WI";
    } else if (officename == "PLO"){
fullname = "Plover, WI";
    } else if (officename == "MADG"){
fullname = "Madison, WI";
    } else if (officename == "MADC"){
fullname = "Madison, WI";
    } else if (officename == "MADR"){
fullname = "Madison, WI";
    } else if (officename == "EDW"){
fullname = "Edwardsville, IL";
    } else if (officename == "CHA"){
fullname = "Charlotte, NC";
```

These format text color based on ping after being run through some else if statements.

```
pingResultHTML = "<span style='color:" + pingColor + "'>" + pingResult + " (" + pingTime + " ms)</span>";
circuitPrimaryResultHTML = "<span style='color:" + linkStatusPrimaryColor + "'>" + linkStatusPrimary + " (" + linkStatusPrimaryTime+ " ms)</span>";
```

This is an example of the data in the txt file.

```
MAD,GOOD,7,GOOD,7
DAV,GOOD,30,GOOD,30
```

Comment: If you have ~20 rows, where are you storing that info? (*An array of objects? JSON that needs to be deserialized?*) Or do you calling the `myCreateFunction()` each time you need to add a row (i.e. calling the function ~20 times)?

Comment: have u considered angularjs? it's simple using angular...

Comment: I'm not seeing how it was stored before. I'm note sure if it fetches it from the txt document each time a popup is click? But the data in the document also determines the color of each dot on the map.

Comment: I added more info to the original post. Hopefully it will make it clearer what I have and where I'm trying to go. @rbtLong I have no idea what angularjs is.

Comment: I ended up building the web page within the Powershell script and outputting the whole thing to a html document. This took the whole output and input problems out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

first You need to adapt data in javascript understandable form like object,map & whatever.....

then you need to just iterate over that like that- 
   Let Suppose data contains you map.

```
var rowCount=1,
table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
   for (var k in data) { 
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');
         for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode((!j)?rowCount++:(j==1)?k:device[k]));
             tr.appendChild(td);
         }
                tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    }
table.appendChild(tbdy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use something like OOP:

```
    function MyTable(data) {
       this.data = data;
       this.rows = [];
       this.container = document.createElement('table');
       this.body = document.createElement('tbody');
       this.container.appendChild(this.body);
       this.render();
    }

    MyTable.prototype.render = function(){
       this.body.innerHTML = '';
       for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
           this.rows.push(new MyRow(this.data[i]));
       }
       for(var j = 0; j < this.rows.length; j++) {
           this.body.appendChild(this.rows[j].container);
       }
    }

    MyTable.prototype.setData= function(data){
       this.data = data;
       this.rows = [];
       this.render();
    }

    function MyRow(data) {
       this.container = document.createElement('tr');
       var name = document.createElement('td');
       name.innerHTML = data.name;
       this.container.appendChild(name);
    }

    var myTable = new MyTable([{name: 'Joe'}, {name: 'Pit'}]);
    document.body.appendChild(myTable.container);
    //data update:
    myTable.setData([{name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'Stephan'}]);
    myTable.render();
```

Comment: Could you help me understand how this works a little bit. I can see that this builds a table using at least one variable. How would I use this with three variables per row, one per column? Also, would this go before or after the original data gets modified?

Comment: I update answer. Also keep in mind that It's just a scratch. Of course you can extend it by some callbacks, custom cell renderers ...etc